# Android Studio [Tab Layout] / Mis tabs miden lo mismo ¿Como puedo cambiar esto?

Tags: android, xml

Me encuentro en una situación en la que tengo una **actividad tabbeada**. El **tab izquierdo** es texto y el **tab derecho** es un ícono. Como el texto ocupa bastante más espacio de largo que el ícono, me gustaría que **el ancho de ambos se ajuste a su  propio tamaño**. En otras palabras, quiero que el tab del ícono sea más pequeño que el tab de texto. Adjunto el código de mi actividad.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.ui.CHAT.fragment_contenedor_chat">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#006064"
            app:tabTextColor="#ffffff"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#b2dfdb" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despues de que se cree la vista podes modificar el ancho asi:

```
LinearLayout layout = ((LinearLayout) ((LinearLayout) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(Indice_del_Tab));
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) layout.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.weight = 0.0f //con este numero le podes asignar un porcentaje fijo relativo a los otros tabs por ejemplo 0.5f sera la mitad que los demas taps y 2f sera el doble
layoutParams.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT //esto sirve si queres que se ajuste al icono que le pusiste y nada mas
layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Si usas weight con un numero distinto de 0.0f pon el widht en 0 para que no se sume y termine quedando raro.

Comment: Erick, muchas gracias por responder. Lo único que no comprendo del código es de donde sale la primer línea de código (LinearLayout layout=...) si es que en mi archivo xml yo no tengo ningún LinearLayout.

Comment: el tablayout internamente tiene un linearlayout. En el ejemplo llame tabLayout al TabLayout que en el xml llamaste tabs

Comment: Listo Erick, tu código me funcionó perfectamente. Me solucionaste un problema que no pude encontrar en ningún lado. Eternas gracias para vos y muy feliz año!